# Polymer - iron-collapse don't work with padding/margin/border

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

As stated in the documentation, iron-collapses don't work with margin, padding or border; but I don't get why?

The documentation just says that  "iron-collapses adjust the width or height of the collapsible element to show/hide content", how is that a relevant reason for not supporting margin or padding on the iron-collapse itself ?

Can someone explains that to me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating (and controlling/animating) sizes when padding/border/margin are involved can be a tricky business and it's a better strategy in general to avoid that problem.

Often you can put your padding/border/margin on elements inside or outside of the `iron-collapse` itself and get the rendering you want.